# Missing intermediate steps for identity

Tags: normal-distribution

Can someone please help fill in the intermediate steps for the following identity:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 = n (\mu - \bar{x}) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2$$

where $\bar{x} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ and $\mu$ is an unknown variable.

--UPDATE in response to amWhy's comment below --

This question is not for a homework assignment or any such task. I am reading a PDF compendium of conjugate priors for fun and saw the above identity, which I was unable to verify on my own. The above identity is found on page 3 of the following link (I realize external links are discouraged, but context was requested: https://www.johndcook.com/CompendiumOfConjugatePriors.pdf).

$$ \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(\mu - \bar{x}) + \sum_{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar{x})^2 \\ 
= \sum_{i=1}^n[ (\mu - \bar{x} + (x_i - \bar{x})^2 ] \\
= \sum_{i=1}^n[ \mu - \bar{x} + x_i^2 -2x_i\bar{x} + \bar{x}^2 ]
$$

I don't see how to turn:
$$ \mu - \bar{x} + x_i^2 -2x_i\bar{x} + \bar{x}^2$$ into
$$ (x_i - \mu)^2 $$

Comment: It doesn't  $\sum (x_i - \mu) = \sum x_i - \sum \mu = n(\bar x -\mu).$  While $\sum (x_i - \bar x)^2 = \sum x_i^2 - n \bar x^2$

Comment: This cannot be correct from dimensional reasons: assume e.g. the $x_i$ are length, so $(x_i - \bar{x})^2$ is a squared  lengths, the other terms are just lengths.$

Comment: I never mentioned homework, nor an assignment.  You've yet to provide where you encountered this problem, your math background, nor the motivation for asking this. Why is this question of interest to you?

Comment: You omitted the exponent on the left.

Comment: @lulu  And that's a comment directed to DougM ?  Might be helpful to address the user or comment, or question, you are commenting about.

Comment: @amWhy  It was directed to the OP.  I looked at the link and noticed that the formula was mis-transcribed.  Just pointing that out.

Comment: @amwhy  Mind you, the formula still appears to be clearly wrong as stated.  If $\mu$ is truly unconnected to the other data, then the left hand is quadratic in $\mu$ but the right hand is linear.

Comment: @lulu:  Your last two comments: Good thing to know.  Hopefully, user2205916 will now know that you were addressing "them" specifically.  Thanks for your usual helpful comments! :)

Comment: Thanks for improving your question! Note that external links in a question are not discouraged, when it provides context. The main question should still be explicitly written out, but it is important to also reference the source of the question. Similarly, answers should not crucially depend on external links, because SE does not and cannot have control over their contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even corrected, I don't think that this is correct.

I think what you should have is.

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 = n(\mu - \bar x)^2 + \sum_\limits{i=1}^n(x-\bar x)^2$

This is also incorrect in the linked document.  Nonetheless,

$\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2\\
\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x + \bar x - \mu)^2\\
\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x)^2 + 2(\bar x - \mu)\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x) + \sum_\limits{i=1}^n(\bar x - \mu)^2\\
\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i -\bar x) = 0\\
\sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_\limits{i=1}^n (x_i - \bar x)^2+n(\bar x - \mu)^2$